# How can I get the distance part of this program to work?

Tags: c

```
/* Shipping Calculator:
Speedy Shipping company will ship your package based on how much it weighs
and how far you are sending the package.  They will only ship small
packages up to 10 pounds.  You need to have a program that will help you
determine how much they will charge.  

The charges are based on each 500 miles shipped.  They are not pro-rated,
i.e., 600 miles is the same charge as 900 miles, i.e.,  600 miles is counted
as 2 segments of 500 miles.     

Here is the table they gave you:

Package Weight                        Rate per 500 miles shipped
2 pounds or less                      $1.50
More than 2 but not more than 6       $3.70
More than 6 but not more than 10      $5.25
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() 
{
    double packageWeight, packageDistance, packagePrice; 

    printf("Enter the weight of the package: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &packageWeight);
    printf("The weight you have entered is %lf\n", packageWeight);

    if (packageWeight <= 2 )
        packagePrice == 1.50;

    if (2 <= packageWeight >= 6) 
            packagePrice == 3.70;

    if (6 <= packageWeight <= 10 )
            packagePrice == 5.25;


    printf("How far are you sending the package? \n");
    scanf("%lf", &packageDistance);
    printf("The distance you entered is %lf\n", packageDistance);       

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Could you be more specific than a simple "it doesn't work", please?

Comment: Well, you haven't said what is wrong with it.  I don't even think this compiles.

Comment: Do you need fractional miles?  If you could use an integer number of miles, then calculating how many units of 500 miles are in use is fairly simple.  It's a bit harder when you use floating point arithmetic, but you can look up [`ceil()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ceil.html).

Comment: its the whole distance part that i dont quite get how to setup

Comment: Hints:  This program does not need any loops.  We are only up to video segment 7.  The program will calculate one shipping charge and stop.  Your test cases should test the various possibilities, and the limits of the program.  

Big Helpful Hint:  You can use integer division, for example:  1200 / 500 =  2

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you mistyped `==` rather than `=`.

Use `==` for comparison and `=` for assignment.

You've also made a syntax mistake on this expression (2 <= packageWeight >= 6), the correct way is (2 <= packageWeight) && (packageWeight >= 6)

Comment: which line are you talking about?

Comment: the line with this code `packagePrice == 1.50`, for example

Comment: ah, indeed :) I thought you were talking about incorrect  comparison. But you were referring to an incorrect assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following sentence：

`packagePrice = x.xx;`

`==` is used to compare while `=` is used to assign a variable